# How to add to css class in a single html tag?

Tags: html, css

I have two different css classes (say class1 and class2). how can I add this two classes to a single html tag (say input box).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this
Need space between two classes.

```
<input type="button" class="class1 class2" />
```

**CSS**

```
.class1{
// class1 css
}
.class2{
//class2 css
}
```

Comment: thanks frnd, Its really help full

Comment: @deepeshkumar  Please accept this answer. It's may be help to others. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just add a space between each class.

```
<input type="text" class="class1 class2" />
```

To style the specific class you would do

```
class1 {
//do styling for class1
}
class1.class2 {
//do styling for class2
}
```